# Href link first and then onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, href

There is a website with a navigation that makes segments appear/disappear on click. It is solved with basic onclick js (making all relevant segments fadeIn() and irrelevants fadeOut() or show()/hide()). This works like a charm thus I do not really intend to change it. The whole site is one single index.html.

I have to make another new.html which will also be available from the navigation, but it has to be separate. So no onclick, but usual href which directs to user to the new new.html. Nothing interesting so far.

The problem is when the user has to get back from new.html to index.html. When the user browses new.html and clicks on any of the navigation elements that brings them back to index.html but the onclick show-hide functions are not called, so the user finds themselves on the mainpage instead of the desired segment of index.html

So is there a way for a href to first load the target (index.html) and then the onclick js? I have found some solutions for the other way around (returning true not false from the onclick thus making it run and then do the href), but cannot find out this one. To be honest I am completely lost at this moment.

The navigation at index.html looks like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-home">Home</div>
    <div class="menu-menu1">Menu1</div>
    <div class="menu-menu2">Menu2</div>
    <div class="menu-newsite"><a href="newsite.html">Newsite</a></div>
</div>
```

While the onclick-s are like this for every menu-item:

```
$('body').on('click', '.menu-menu1', function(){
    $('.menu-home').hide();
    $('.menu-menu1').show();
    $('.menu-menu2').fadeOut();
});
```

On the new.html I want to have a menu like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
    <div class="menu-menu1"><a href="index.html" onclick="here comes something that will get back to index.html but with menu1 showing">Menu1</a></div>
    <div class="menu-menu2"><a href="index.html" onclick="here comes something that will get back to index.html but with menu2 showing">Menu2</a></div>
    <div class="menu-newsite"><a href="newsite.html">Newsite</a></div>
</div>
```

This href+onclick might not be the solution, but this is the only might-be-possible way I have found in answers - though the other way around: onclick action first and then the href link.

Comment: You're not going to get good responses because as it stands this question is too broad.  You really need to do some work and produce an [mcve]

Comment: need to see some code on this one. It sounds like it may be the way you are referencing your href's. Are they absolute or relative? Are you setting the target attribute of the href.

Comment: Adding some code to it now, just a minute.

Comment: You could use a query string to pass the desired open menu to your main index page.

Comment: Alternately you could set a local storage variable that your index page checks on load.

Comment: The approach UltrasoundJelly suggested might work for you. But ultimately I think you have to rethink your architecture. Why don't you use AJAX to load only the content needed and combine this with a simple router like [routie.js](http://projects.jga.me/routie/)? Then you can reference any content in page a with a simple link on page b. A callback in the router function on page a will take care of loading the desired content.

Comment: Thanks UltrasoundJelly and Flyer53 I will look into your suggestions later today and come back with the results.